# EdmGen not supporting .Net Framework version 4.7.2

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7.2, edmgen

EdmGen.exe is not supporting targetversion 4.7.2.

Exception thrown as  "**error 7025: Only .NET Framework version 4 and 4.5 are supported. To use another version use the tools that shipped with that version.**"

To the best of my knowledge there is latest version of EdmGen.exe. Is there any way that I can generate edmx with target .net framework  version 4.7.2 ...?

Comment: install it? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: @mxmissile the link you have provided is pointing to .Net4.5.  Is that mean I have to change my targetversion to 4.5 ...?  All my projects are compiling with 4.7.2 version.